# Linear transformation?Rotation question in linear algebra

Tags: linear-algebra

Given the vector $x=[1, 3, -7]^T$ in the basis $[1, 0, 0]^T$, $[0, 1, 0]^T$, and $[0, 0, 1]^T$ (Cartesian coordinates) perform the following operations:

Rotate 45 degrees about the x-axis
then rotate 30 degrees about the y-axis
then rotate -10 degrees about the z-axis

I have absolutely no idea how to start this problem.  I can't find any examples.  I will continue to look on this website for examples as well.

I do know that the rotation matrix is:

$$ Q= \left[ \begin{array}{cc} \cos(\theta) &  -\sin(\theta) \\ \sin(\theta) &   \cos(\theta) \end{array} \right] $$

The question does go on to ask for reflections and projections about and onto various axis.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  All of you math wizards have given me some great help!!  Thanks!!

Comment: you'll need to perform the operations in the order in which they are given to you. Beware that rotations need not commute!

Comment: @Lanae: You can look at [*examples 3-24 through 3-26*](http://books.google.com/books?id=qVvWjf-x-pUC&pg=PA183&lpg=PA183&dq=rotation+operator+r%5E3&source=bl&ots=eX-kG0W3Up&sig=4wFNzn7OUWRSq5PoCIllroNd82U&hl=en&sa=X&ei=FvG7UdHAJuvDyAGRjoHoBA&ved=0CGAQ6AEwCQ#v=onepage&q=rotation%20operator%20r%5E3&f=false) for James Cook's nice answer.

Comment: @Amzoti~ thanks for the link.  I'm using Strang and it doesn't have examples like that.  I'll have to reference that link some more for more linear transformation problems.  :)

Comment: @Lanae: You are very welcome! Have fun!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The matrix you need will be $3 \times 3$ and it is formed by taking the matrix you wrote and adjusting it a bit. Basically, you want to fix the axis of the rotation and twist the other two directions. To fix the $z$-direction use:
$$ R = \left[ \begin{array}{ccc}
\cos(\theta) & -\sin(\theta) & 0 \\
\sin(\theta) & \cos(\theta) & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \end{array} \right] $$
To fix the $y$-direction (which means $x$ and $z$ directions are rotated) use:
$$ R = \left[ \begin{array}{ccc}
\cos(\theta) & 0 & -\sin(\theta) \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
\sin(\theta) & 0 & \cos(\theta) \end{array} \right] $$
and finally, to rotate around the $x$-axis:
$$ R = \left[ \begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & \cos(\theta) & -\sin(\theta) \\
0 & \sin(\theta) & \cos(\theta) \end{array} \right] $$
maybe you should try some simple examples with my suggestions to see how these work. Pick an easy angle and a simple vector and test the transformations.

Comment: and Amzoti~  I just watched a Kahn Academy video on rotations.  Thanks James for the matrices! And I will check out the links provided.  I assume for the reflections and projections I will need to expand on the R^2 matrices given to perform the operations in R^3.  You guys are much appreciated!!

Comment: @Lanae glad to help. Fun fact while we're on the topic. You can measure the angle by which a rotation matrix rotates by looking at the trace in each case $tr(R) =  1 +2\cos(\theta)$. This is invariant under a similarity transformation, so even for less easy rotation matrices where all 9 entries are nontrivial you can measure the angle by that formula. It turns out that any matrix in $SO(3)$ is a rotation around some axis. Enjoy the math!